# distinct-values in XML

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

please someone can help with distinct in xpath? I am trying to make some query that returns the amount of different actors that were born after the year and that have more than the award amount in one movie or one TV-show.

so first i select the all actors that their birth of year is above the year parameter and than i use count for count their awards. but now i have duplicates names, how can i distinct my result?

my code:

```
public int Query6(XmlDocument xmlDoc, String yearOfBirth, int amountOfAwards)
        {
            string s = "//actors/actor[year-of-birth>'" + yearOfBirth + "'][count(awards/award)>"+amountOfAwards+"]";

            XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(s);
            return xmlNodeList.Count;
        }
```

XMLDoc:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Netflix>
  <movies>
    <movie>
      <name>Mister Glass</name>
      <genre>Drama</genre>
      <year>2019</year>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>James</first-name>
          <last-name>McAvoy</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1979 </year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Alliance of Women Film Journalists</category>
              <year>2007</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>ALOS Awards</category>
              <year>2018</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Bruce</first-name>
          <last-name>Willis</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1955 </year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>American gun rights advocates</category>
              <year>2007</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>American film producers</category>
              <year>2013</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>American male video game actors</category>
              <year>2012</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>American male television actors</category>
              <year>2013</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
      </actors>
    </movie>
    <movie>
      <name>Aquaman</name>
      <genre>Action</genre>
      <year>2018</year>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Jason</first-name>
          <last-name>Momoa</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1979</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Rising Star</category>
              <year>2011</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Amber</first-name>
          <last-name>Heard</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1986</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Dallas Star Award</category>
              <year>2010</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>Spotlight Award</category>
              <year>2011</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
      </actors>
    </movie>
    <movie>
      <name>Split</name>
      <genre>Horror</genre>
      <year>2016</year>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>James</first-name>
          <last-name>McAvoy</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1979 </year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Best Actor - Audience Award</category>
              <year>2017</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
      </actors>
    </movie>
    <movie>
      <name>harry potter</name>
      <genere>fantasy</genere>
      <year>1997</year>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Daniel</first-name>
          <last-name>Radcliffe</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1989</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Male Youth Discovery of the Year</category>
              <year>2001</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>Choice Movie: Male Breakout Star</category>
              <year>2001</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>Best Actor</category>
              <year>2008</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
        <actor>
          <first-name>emma</first-name>
          <last-name>watson</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1990</year-of-birth>
        </actor>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Alba</first-name>
          <last-name>Florez</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1986</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Best Female Performer in Fiction</category>
              <year>2000</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
      </actors>
    </movie>
    <movie>
      <name>Miss Bala </name>
      <genre>Action</genre>
      <year>2019</year>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Gina</first-name>
          <last-name>Rodriguez</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1984</year-of-birth>
        </actor>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Thomas</first-name>
          <last-name>Dekker</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1987</year-of-birth>
        </actor>
      </actors>
    </movie>
    <movie>
      <name>The Dark Knight</name>
      <genre>Action</genre>
      <year>2008</year>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Christian</first-name>
          <last-name>Bale</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1974</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Best Actor</category>
              <year>2013</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>Best Cast Ensemble</category>
              <year>2008</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
      </actors>
    </movie>
    <movie>
      <name>Forrest Gump</name>
      <genre>Drama</genre>
      <year>1994</year>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Tom</first-name>
          <last-name>Hanks</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1956</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Best Actor in a Leading Role</category>
              <year>1994</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>Best Performance by an Actor in a Motion Picture - Drama</category>
              <year>1995</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Robin</first-name>
          <last-name>Wright</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1966</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Best Performance by an Actress in a Supporting Role in a Motion Picture</category>
              <year>1994</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
      </actors>
    </movie>
    <movie>
      <name>Star Wars</name>
      <genre>Action</genre>
      <year>1977</year>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Harrison</first-name>
          <last-name>Ford</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1942</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Best Actor</category>
              <year>1997</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Mark</first-name>
          <last-name>Hamill</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1951</year-of-birth>
        </actor>
      </actors>
    </movie>
    <movie>
      <name>Gladiator</name>
      <genre>Action</genre>
      <year>2000</year>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Russell</first-name>
          <last-name>Crowe</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1964</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Best Actor in a Leading Role</category>
              <year>2000</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>Best Performance by an Actor in a Motion Picture - Drama</category>
              <year>2000</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Joaquin</first-name>
          <last-name>Phoenix</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1974</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Best Actor in a Supporting Role</category>
              <year>2000</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>Best Performance by an Actor in a Supporting Role in a Motion Picture</category>
              <year>2000</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
      </actors>
    </movie>
    <movie>
      <name>Ted</name>
      <genre>Comedy</genre>
      <year>2015</year>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Mila</first-name>
          <last-name>Kunis</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1983</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Young Artist Awards</category>
              <year>2001</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>Teen Choice Awards</category>
              <year>2010</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
      </actors>
    </movie>
  </movies>
  <TV-shows>
    <TV-show>
      <name>Narcos</name>
      <genre>Crime</genre>
      <year>2015</year>
      <seasons>
        <season>
          <episodes>10</episodes>
        </season>
        <season>
          <episodes>10</episodes>
        </season>
        <season>
          <episodes>10</episodes>
        </season>
      </seasons>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Wagner</first-name>
          <last-name>Maniçoba de Moura</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1976</year-of-birth>
        </actor>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Pedro</first-name>
          <last-name>Pascal</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1975</year-of-birth>
        </actor>
        <actor>
          <first-name>James</first-name>
          <last-name>Clarke</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1986</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Outstanding Female Rising Star in a Drama Series or Special</category>
              <year>2012</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Daniel</first-name>
          <last-name>Radcliffe</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1989</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Male Youth Discovery of the Year</category>
              <year>2001</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>Choice Movie: Male Breakout Star</category>
              <year>2001</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>Best Actor</category>
              <year>2008</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
      </actors>
    </TV-show>
    <TV-show>
      <name>Game of Thrones</name>
      <genre>Action</genre>
      <year>2011</year>
      <seasons>
        <season>
          <episodes>10</episodes>
        </season>
        <season>
          <episodes>10</episodes>
        </season>
        <season>
          <episodes>10</episodes>
        </season>
        <season>
          <episodes>10</episodes>
        </season>
        <season>
          <episodes>10</episodes>
        </season>
        <season>
          <episodes>10</episodes>
        </season>
        <season>
          <episodes>7</episodes>
        </season>
      </seasons>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Emilia</first-name>
          <last-name>Clarke</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1986</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Outstanding Female Rising Star in a Drama Series or Special</category>
              <year>2012</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>Best Supporting Actress in a Drama Series</category>
              <year>2013</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>Breakout Performance - Female</category>
              <year>2011</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Peter</first-name>
          <last-name>Dinklage</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1969</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Outstanding Supporting Actor in a Drama Series</category>
              <year>2018</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
      </actors>
    </TV-show>
    <TV-show>
      <name>The Sopranos</name>
      <genre>Crime</genre>
      <year>1999</year>
      <seasons>
        <season>
          <episodes>13</episodes>
        </season>
        <season>
          <episodes>13</episodes>
        </season>
        <season>
          <episodes>13</episodes>
        </season>
        <season>
          <episodes>13</episodes>
        </season>
        <season>
          <episodes>13</episodes>
        </season>
        <season>
          <episodes>21</episodes>
        </season>
      </seasons>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>James</first-name>
          <last-name>Gandolfini</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1961</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Best Performance by an Actor in a Television Series - Drama</category>
              <year>2000</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>Outstanding Lead Actor in a Drama Series</category>
              <year>2003</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Lorraine</first-name>
          <last-name>Bracco</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1954</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Outstanding Performance by an Ensemble in a Drama Series</category>
              <year>2008</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
      </actors>
    </TV-show>
    <TV-show>
      <name>Black Mirror</name>
      <genre>Drama</genre>
      <year>2011</year>
      <seasons>
        <season>
          <episodes>3</episodes>
        </season>
        <season>
          <episodes>3</episodes>
        </season>
        <season>
          <episodes>6</episodes>
        </season>
        <season>
          <episodes>6</episodes>
        </season>
      </seasons>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Daniel</first-name>
          <last-name>Lapaine</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1971</year-of-birth>
        </actor>
      </actors>
    </TV-show>
    <TV-show>
      <name>Westworld</name>
      <genre>Drama</genre>
      <year>2016</year>
      <seasons>
        <season>
          <episodes>10</episodes>
        </season>
        <season>
          <episodes>10</episodes>
        </season>
      </seasons>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Jeffrey</first-name>
          <last-name>Wright</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1965</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Best TV Actor</category>
              <year>2016</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Ed</first-name>
          <last-name>Harris</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1950</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Best Supporting Actor on Television</category>
              <year>2017</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
      </actors>
    </TV-show>
    <TV-show>
      <name>Big Little Lies</name>
      <genre>Crime</genre>
      <year>2017</year>
      <seasons>
        <season>
          <episodes>7</episodes>
        </season>
      </seasons>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Reese</first-name>
          <last-name>Witherspoon</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1976</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Outstanding Limited Series</category>
              <year>2017</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Nicole</first-name>
          <last-name>Kidman</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1967</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Best Performance by an Actress in a Limited Series or a Motion Picture Made for Television</category>
              <year>2018</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>Outstanding Lead Actress in a Limited Series or Movie</category>
              <year>2017</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
      </actors>
    </TV-show>
    <TV-show>
      <name>The Night Of</name>
      <genre>Crime</genre>
      <year>2016</year>
      <seasons>
        <season>
          <episodes>8</episodes>
        </season>
      </seasons>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Riz</first-name>
          <last-name>Ahmed</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1982</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Outstanding Lead Actor in a Limited Series or Movie</category>
              <year>2017</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
        <actor>
          <first-name>John</first-name>
          <last-name>Turturro</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1957</year-of-birth>
        </actor>
      </actors>
    </TV-show>
    <TV-show>
      <name>Mr. Bean</name>
      <genre>Comedy</genre>
      <year>1990</year>
      <seasons>
        <season>
          <episodes>15</episodes>
        </season>
      </seasons>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Rowan</first-name>
          <last-name>Atkinson</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1955</year-of-birth>
        </actor>
      </actors>
    </TV-show>
    <TV-show>
      <name>The Handmaid's Tale</name>
      <genre>Drama</genre>
      <year>2017</year>
      <seasons>
        <season>
          <episodes>10</episodes>
        </season>
        <season>
          <episodes>13</episodes>
        </season>
      </seasons>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Elisabeth</first-name>
          <last-name>Moss </last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1982</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Best Performance by an Actress in a Television Series - Drama</category>
              <year>2018</year>
            </award>
            <award>
              <category>Outstanding Drama Series</category>
              <year>2017</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Max</first-name>
          <last-name>Minghella</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1985</year-of-birth>
        </actor>
      </actors>
    </TV-show>
    <TV-show>
      <name>Casa De Papel</name>
      <genre>Drama</genre>
      <year>2017</year>
      <seasons>
        <season>
          <episodes>13</episodes>
        </season>
        <season>
          <episodes>9</episodes>
        </season>
      </seasons>
      <actors>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Alba</first-name>
          <last-name>Florez</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1986</year-of-birth>
          <awards>
            <award>
              <category>Best Supporting Actress in a Television Series </category>
              <year>2015</year>
            </award>
          </awards>
        </actor>
        <actor>
          <first-name>Álvaro</first-name>
          <last-name>Morte</last-name>
          <year-of-birth>1975</year-of-birth>
        </actor>
      </actors>
    </TV-show>
  </TV-shows>
</Netflix>
```

so for example if i choose year 1980 and 3 awards so in my result "Daniel Radcliffe" will count twice and i want him only 1.

i am writing in c#.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following.

```
var result = xDocument.Descendants("actor")
     .Where(x=>x.Descendants("award").Any()) // You can skip this is if you want to consider Actors who haven't won any award
     .Select(x=>new 
     {
        Actor=$"{x.Element("first-name").Value} {x.Element("last-name").Value}",
        YearOfBirth = Int32.Parse(x.Element("year-of-birth").Value),
        AwardCount = x.Descendants("award").Count()
    })
    .GroupBy(x=>x.Actor)
    .Where(x=>x.First().YearOfBirth>Int32.Parse(yearOfBirth) && x.Sum(c=>c.AwardCount)>amountOfAwards)
    .Select(x=> new 
    {
        Actor = x.Key,
        YearOfBirth = x.First().YearOfBirth,
        Awards = x.Sum(c=>c.AwardCount)
    });
```

**Output (for year 1980, amountOfAwards 3)**

[image]

Comment: there is no way that i can do it with XPATH?

Comment: As @Michael Kay wrote in the other answer: you can it with XPath (version 2.0+), but not with XPath version 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done easily in XPath 1.0, but it is easy with XPath 2.0. The Microsoft XPath engine bundled with .NET does not support XPath 2.0, but there are alternatives from third parties (for example Saxon) that do.

I'm not sure exactly what output you want, but if you do a query that selects a set of `actor` elements (let's say the result is in $selectedActors), then you can get the distinct names of those actors using

`distinct-values($selectedActors/concat(first-name, ' ', last-name))`

XPath has come a long way since 1.0. Unfortunately Microsoft has never implemented later versions: they would prefer you to move to their own proprietary technologies (LINQ). Whether you move to LINQ or to later XPath engines from third parties depends on your attitude to Microsoft lock-in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that XQuery is capable of what you want, as you have multiple entries with the same actor. That means you need to aggregate across elements to get the total awards for an actor.

Here is a solution that uses Linq to achieve the same result:

```
public class Actor
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Awards { get; set; }
    public int BirthYear { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode() => 0;

    public override bool Equals(object obj) =>(obj as Actor)?.Name.Equals(this.Name) ?? base.Equals(obj);
}


public IEnumerable<Actor> GetActorsAndAwards(XDocument xml)
{
    foreach (var actor in xml.XPathSelectElements(@"//actors/actor"))
    {
        yield return new Actor
        {
            Name = $"{actor.Element("first-name").Value}, {actor.Element("last-name").Value}",
            Awards = actor.XPathSelectElements(@"awards/award").Count(),
            BirthYear = int.Parse(actor.Element("year-of-birth").Value)
        };
    };
}

public IEnumerable<Actor> AggregateAndFilter(IEnumerable<Actor> actors, int yearOfBirth, int amountOfAwards)
    => actors
        .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
        .Select(x => new Actor { Name = x.Key, BirthYear = x.First().BirthYear, Awards = x.Sum(y => y.Awards) })
        .Where(x => x.BirthYear > yearOfBirth && x.Awards > amountOfAwards)
        ;


void Main()
{
    var xml = XDocument.Load(@"D:\Temp\0\netflix.xml");

    AggregateAndFilter(GetActorsAndAwards(xml), 1970, 2).Count().Dump(); //Dump is LinqPad tool, do whatever you want with the result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need an XPath 1.0 solution, you could use this query to get all actors with a unique last name:

`/Netflix/*/*/actors/actor[not(last-name = preceding::actor/last-name)`

Of course, this means that Jeffrey Wright and Robin Wright are not seen as unique actors. You can add more criteria like this:

`/Netflix/*/*/actors/actor[not(last-name = preceding::actor/last-name) or not(first-name = preceding::actor/first-name) or not(year-of-birth = preceding::actor/year-of-birth)]`, in which case the record will be seen unique if it has a unique last name, or a unique first name, or a unique year of birth. But this is obviously not waterproof! This only becomes a valid solution if you can add a unique ID for each actor. Without it, I don't think it is actually possible to do it in pure XPath 1.0.